# Function to open, read csv file and create 2D list

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, csv

for my course I need to create a function that opens a csv file, reads it, creates a 2D list and that gives the list a name. There are several csv files so the idea is that I refer to the read_file function and input the file name parameter. See image for code. I cant seem to input the file name an a parameter. Any help?

function attempt:

[image]

Comment: The filename needs to be a string, put quotes

Comment: you don't wrap kameraData.csv on a string? -> change it to 'kameraData.csv'

Comment: (1) Put the filename in quotes - `"kameraData.csv"`; (2) `read_file` doesn't return anything, add `return data_list` at the end of the function

Comment: Also the 'filename' on line 5 doesnt need a quote because it is a  variable, also i suggest to improve your basic python programming :) (no hate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the already posted comments, you then need to un-quote the filename after the `with open`. Since if you now call with file_name as a string already, you need the quotes there anymore. So like this:

```
def read_file(file_name):
    ....
    with open(file_name, 'r', ...) as f:
        ...

read_file('kameraData.csv')
```